# Full specialization of template taking integer parameter returning std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I have the following function:

```
template<int numIntervals>
class DivideIntervalsImpl {
public:
    static std::array<std::pair<int, int>, numIntervals> divideIntervals(int begin, int NITEM);
};
```

which basically returns an array of 2-tuples (int, int), indicating the access locations for a multithreaded parser.

The implementation for numIntervals != 1 is

```
template<int numIntervals> std::array<std::pair<int, int>, numIntervals> DivideIntervalsImpl<numIntervals>::divideIntervals(int begin, int NITEM) {
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, numIntervals> intervals;

    //Interval size of the last-but-one parsing task
    int intervalWidth = std::floor((float)(NITEM - numIntervals) / (float)numIntervals);

    //Interval size of the last task
    int lastIntervalWidth = NITEM - (numIntervals - 1) * intervalWidth;

    intervals.at(0) = { begin, begin + intervalWidth - 1 };

    for (int i = 1; i < numIntervals - 1; ++i) {
    intervals.at(i) = { intervals.at(i - 1).second + 1, (intervals.at(i - 1).second + intervalWidth) };
    }

    intervals.at(numIntervals - 1) = { intervals.at(numIntervals - 2).second + 1, intervals.at(numIntervals - 2).second + lastIntervalWidth };
    return intervals;
};
```

Which works perfectly.

For numIntervals = 1, we can just say:

```
template<> std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1> DivideIntervalsImpl<1>::divideIntervals(int begin, int NITEM) {
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1> intervals;

    //Interval size
    int intervalWidth = NITEM - 1;
    intervals.at(0) = { begin, begin + intervalWidth };
    return intervals;   
};
```

This could be a nice thing.. But it does not compile, there are errors in the full specialization part.
I'm very confused, because the errors do not make sense!

First line of the full specialization
`'intervals' uses undefined class 'std::array<std::pair<int,int>,1>'`

last-but-one
`left of '.at' must have class/struct/union`

Line with `};`
`use of undefined type 'std::array<std::pair<int,int>,1>'`

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with MSVC v141 and C++17.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Could you create a [mcve]? Because as posted, your code compiles just fine on all [three compilers](https://godbolt.org/g/RNSsqG).

Comment: I do see similar error messages from MSVC if I comment out `#include <array>`.

Comment: Actually, those two includes got lost while refactoring. But they are not the only reason the code did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specialize ***the entire class***, instead of its sole class method:

```
template<>
class DivideIntervalsImpl<1> {
public:
    static std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1> divideIntervals(int begin, int NITEM)
    {
        std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1> intervals;

        //Interval size
        int intervalWidth = NITEM - 1;
        intervals.at(0) = { begin, begin + intervalWidth };
        return intervals;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why? Specializing a member of a class template is legal.

Comment: @aschepler it is necessary.
Specializing only the member produces some linker errors.

Comment: @java4ever Sounds like you put the explicit specialization in a header file without the `inline` keyword. Since an explicit specialization does not have any template parameters, it acts like a non-template function as far as the ODR goes. You can either declare the specialization in the header and define it in a source file, or add `inline` in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem with minimal code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
class foo
{
public:
    static std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> bar();
};

template<std::size_t N>
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> foo<N>::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Generic\n";
    return std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N>{};
}

template<>
inline std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1> foo<1>::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Special\n";
    return std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1>{};
}

int main()
{
    auto a = foo<5u>{};
    auto b = foo<1u>{};
    a.bar();
    b.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Genric
Special
```

For

- clang 3.8
- gcc 6.3
- msvc 19.00